# Kinesis Shard GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds reached maximum 86.4M (1 day) and does not decrease even though consuming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl

- I am consuming a Kinesis stream with Spark Streaming 2.2.0 and using **spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11**.
- Kinesis Stream has 150 shards and I am monitoring `GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds` CloudWatch metric to see whether consumer is keeping up with the stream.
- Kinesis Stream has a default data retention of 86400 seconds (1 day).
- I am debugging a case where a few Kinesis Shards reached maximum `GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds` of 86400000 (== retention period)
- This is only true for some shards (let's call them **outdated shards**), not all of them.

I have identified shardIds for **outdated shards**. One of them is `shardId-000000000518` and I can see in DynamoDB table that holds checkpointing information the following:

```
leaseKey: shardId-000000000518
checkpoint: 49578988488125109498392734939028905131283484648820187234
checkpointSubSequenceNumber: 0
leaseCounter: 11058
leaseOwner: 10.0.165.44:52af1b14-3ed0-4b04-90b1-94e4d178ed6e    
ownerSwitchesSinceCheckpoint: 37
parentShardId: { "shardId-000000000269" }
```

I can see the following in the logs of worker on 10.0.165.44:

> 17/11/22 01:04:14 INFO Worker: Current stream shard assignments: shardId-000000000339, ..., shardId-000000000280, **shardId-000000000518**

... which should mean that **shardId-000000000518** was assigned to this worker. However, I never see anything else in the logs for this shardId. If the worker is not consuming from this shardId (but it should), this can explain why `GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds` never decreases. For some other (non-**outdated shardIds**), I can see in the logs

> 17/11/22 01:31:28 INFO SequenceNumberValidator: Validated sequence number 49578988151227751784190049362310810844771023726275728690 with shard id shardId-00000000033

I did verify that **outdated shards** have data flowing into them by looking at the IncomingRecords CloudWatch metric.

How can I debug/resolve this? Why would these shardIds never get picked up and by the Spark worker?